# How to switch user using cyber duck for transferring files to linux server?

Tags: ssh, sftp

The situation was like this. I was given a key by sysop. It was named after me. When I log in to terminal I just do:

```
ssh -i keyfile username@ip
```

so in the server I am logged as myself, but I need to do

```
sudo su dev
```

in order to be able to access some directories.
Now my problem is, according to the sysop  there's no limitation of my permissions with that keyfile. I can do anything on the server with it.
"But", when I tried to use cyberduck for mac, I wasn't able to drag and drop files because I cannot do `sudo su dev` in cyberduck, as the keyfile is named after me. So how do I do `sudo su dev` , hence switch to that `dev` name in order to be able to drag and drop files in cyberduck? Because now, all I can do is,just see the directories and files in the server using that ssh client.Unless I go to terminal and do sudo su dev

Comment: few clarification needed: a keyfile doesn't provide permissions, the key provide authentication to a specific user, then the user on the remote server a certain privileges.

Comment: he told me to do scp , but when I search youtube for tutorials , I find it too troublesome to use scp because I need to type very long file paths just to test some codes. that's why I wish to use a drag and drop client to ease the pain

Comment: it seems the design of user permissions is kind of flawed for your use-case. The sysops guys should have make a group called `dev` which the user you use to login belongs to in order to make that work. Try perhaps adding a `sudo su dev` at the very end of the file `.bashrc` on the remote server.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because your sysops team needs to resolve this with your cooperation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't normally `sudo` over `scp` or `sftp`, but you can from an `ssh` command prompt. I don't know how `Cyberduck` works but I see it does `sftp`, so I think you're out of luck.

You should get a key to access the `dev` account directly or have your sysadmin change permissions or something to allow you to do your work.

There's this discussion about different ways to get around copying files as root with scp when you're not root. One guy even wrote his own script (scroll down).

https://askubuntu.com/questions/208378/how-do-i-copy-files-that-need-root-access-with-scp

**The good news** is that it looks like WinSCP has some trickery built in to allow you to `sudo` after connecting and before using `sftp`. Perhaps you can run it via [Wine](http://winebottler.kronenberg.org/).

If you want to use Cyberduck, I suggest going to your sysadmin and making him fix all this or read it's manual and hope it does what WinSCP claims to do.

Comment: thanks for the winscp tip sir, I saw the trick you're talking about. just have to use wine to make it work ..cheers

Comment: winscp is rejecting the my attempted connection...darn.....it only allows me to connect sftp ...but when I go to the mac terminal I can actually switch user using `sudo su dev`

Comment: @sasori What are you doing on this server? Your question was put on hold because some people believe you are not administering a server or network. Perhaps, if you are doing such a thing, you can update your original question to make that clear.